# Installing Packages From Source

Tags: source, lfs

I have been trying different Linux distributions lately to learn as much as about Linux. Lately, I have encountered with installing packages from source while trying to learn about the core elements of Linux while installing LFS. I have managed to install some packages from the source, but there is no standard in the process. Yes, the general approach is to first configure, then make, then make install but from package to package this changes a lot. And I haven't yet found an approach to deal with any package I want to install.

For example, I am trying to install dpkg package manager and I managed to successfully install all the dependencies except one; libselinux1. There is no configure file in the folder after extracting the tarball, so I thought I should go with make step first, skipping configure. I have read the Makefile inside the folder, it gave me no idea. And it did not work giving an error saying:

```
Fatal Error: sepol/sepol.h: No such file or directory
15 | #include <sepol/sepol.h>
```

My question is how can I know how to install any package from source without using package managers? And more specifically, how can I install this package?

Many thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

> My question is how can I know how to install any package from source without using package managers?

There's no standard for source code compilation. Various packages may use `Makefile`, `cmake`, `autotools`, plain bash scripts, `meson`, `waf` and [many others](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_build_automation_software).

> And more specifically, how can I install this package?

You can check how

- Arch builds it : https://aur.archlinux.org/cgit/aur.git/tree/PKGBUILD?h=libselinux
- Fedora https://src.fedoraproject.org/rpms/libselinux/blob/master/f/libselinux.spec or
- Debian http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/a/android-platform-external-libselinux/android-platform-external-libselinux_8.1.0+r23-2.debian.tar.xz
- or even Gentoo https://gitweb.gentoo.org/repo/gentoo.git/tree/sys-libs/libselinux/libselinux-3.1.ebuild